# Strapi V4 Modify user data saved after login with Microsoft Provider

Tags: azure-active-directory, strapi

I'm using Strapi V4 and have configured Microsoft Azure Active Directory as the provider to login. By default, this extracts basic information like the users email and saves it to the Strapi User. Active Directory provides additional fields, like user groups and roles, and I'd like those values to be saved on the Strapi User too. Each time the user logs in I'd like it to update the Strapi user record in case the users Active Directory values change.

How do you modify the core user record information that is saved when using a custom provider?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a webhook that will periodically sync the group membership from Azure AD to Strapi.

To set up a webhook that will periodically sync the group membership from Azure AD to Strapi, you will need to follow the steps which include installing and configuring the Azure AD integration plugin for Strapi, creating a subscription using the Azure AD Graph API, and creating a server-side script to handle the incoming webhook request and update the user roles in Strapi.

You would like to connect with Strapi for the script and webhook setup.

Thanks